# How do I make my header div scroll until it reaches the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, header, scroll, fixed

I'm currently using fixed positioning to keep my header at the top of the page, even as users scroll. However, I'd like to add a logo and other content above the header, but not remain fixed like the header does. Is there a way to use CSS or HTML to have the header scroll normally with this content until the header reaches the top of the page, where it will act as it does now and hover above the text on the page?

**Update**

I'm not very experienced with jQuery and Javascript. This is the HTML code for my header:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="clients/index.html">Clients</a></li>
            </ul>
                <div class="logobackground">
                    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
                </div>
            <ul class="pull-right">
              <li><a href=“mailto:........@...biz">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What Javascript or jQuery would I have to use and where would I put it in my site's directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need javascript (jquery) for this.

The following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5n4pF/4/ (not the neetest example) show how to do this. The most important thing is that the jquery is correct. You should use:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 147) {
            $("#top_nav").addClass("fixed");

        } else {
            $("#top_nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }
});
```

now you can style your #top_nav.fixed so it will stay at the top of the page and your #top_nav so it has a normal position.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better, as I always use this approach while doing these kind of things.

**Steps:**

1. Handle `window`'s `.onscroll` event
2. Fetch `window.pageYOffset`
3. Set div's `.style.marginTop` to `window.pageYOffset` with a ternary operator(condition for stopping it).

Like for example:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginTop = window.pageYOffset <= 147 ? 147 : window.pageYOffset;
}
```

*Note: Never use jQuery for these type of small things. It puts load onto the server.*

Comment: I'm confused as to your note.  jQuery/JavaScript is client side code.  How does it put load on the server?

Comment: 2nd that. Anyways jquery is about 96kb, and most content management systems already have jquery included. So shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten it should be a problem, do you know how do they manage their sites?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui What do you mean?